# Automating addition of members to non-Workspace Google Group

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

Is there a sensible way to automate the addition of members to a **non-Workspace** google group? I can't seem to find any API or other resource not reserved for workspace members.

*Use case:* I would like to be able to invite users after they submit a contact form without doing so manually following the steps listed here in the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465464?hl=en&ref_topic=2458761).